# Why is Outlook losing HTML formatting on e-mail sent from SQL?

Tags: html, css, email, outlook, html-email

I have an e-mail I create in SQL Server Management Studio with a body of HTML.  In the HTML, I have CSS to change the background color of some rows in a table.  When I view the HTML, it looks fine; however when the e-mail gets delivered, none of the rows in the table have the background color.  Is Outlook 365 simply stripping out color styles?  Is there anyway to keep the back color in the e-mail or anyway to approximate highlighting a row in the HTML?

Here are screenshots of the HTML, the HTML as viewed in a browser, and the HTML as seen in the e-mail (please ignore the black blocks, I'm hiding customer information):
[image]

Here's the SQL code to send the e-mail:

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
@execute_query_database = 'xxxx',
@profile_name = @profile,
@blind_copy_recipients = 'xxxx',
@subject = @subj,
@body = @body,
@body_format = 'HTML'
```

Comment: If you are expecting outlook to format your HTML like a modern browser then prepare to be disappointed - afaik it still uses an old IE rendering engine. you also don't appear to have valid html I don't see a closing `</tr>`?

Comment: See [Word 2007 HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities in Outlook 2007](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338201(v=office.12))

Answer (score 1):

Background-color should be on a `<td>` or `<th>`, not `<tr>`.